# Docker - failed to load listeners, cannot assign requested address

Tags: docker, ubuntu-server, portainer

So i have recently changed my ISP over and theyve given me a new router. All was good and well until i plugged my network switch in. All of a sudden, docker started crying and now i can't run any services.

All i know that has changed in the local ip address from 192.168.1.195 to 192.168.4.31.

This was the first time trying to start the service again

```
mhudson@Guardian:~$ sudo dockerd
INFO[2023-01-16T19:25:41.710343685Z] Starting up
failed to load listeners: listen tcp 192.168.1.195:2376: bind: cannot assign requested address
```

This is a command i saw on a thread.

```
mhudson@Guardian:~$ sudo echo `ifconfig enp1s0 | grep -E "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk '{ print $2;exit }' | cut -f2 -d:`
192.168.4.31
```

If someone could help as i rely on the services on the daily. Please and thank you.

Comment: That port 2376 sort of sounds like it's trying to make the Docker socket available over the network.  Are you doing that intentionally?  Anyone who can access the Docker socket can pretty trivially take over the entire host; a correct mTLS setup can mitigate the risk somewhat, but it still sounds dangerous.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand the problem. I knew that port was significant but i couldn't for the life of me think what for. It had portainer installed, which i would control using anget within my other instance of portainer from my main server. I will try to remove portainer and the agent without disturbing my containers and report back.